# Haskell: Sum of last 2 integers in a string

Tags: string, haskell, recursion, sum, integer

I am new to Haskell and I'm attempting a task in which the result should be the sum of the last two integers in a string.

I completely understand the overall addition part however it is the manipulation of the string recursively that I'm struggling with. To attempt the task I first 'flipped' the string with the last integer becoming the first for said string to be split after the nth term, in this case 2.

For example, with the given string 1,2,3,4,5,6,7. The result would be 13 as in 6+7=13.

```
sum' :: [a] -> [a]
sum' = foldl (\acc x -> x : acc) []

sum' :: [a] -> [a]
sum' [] = []
sum' xs = let h = splitAt 1 xs in h

sum' :: (Num a) => [a] -> a 
sum' [] = 0 
sum' (xs:x) = xs + sum' (x)

main :: IO()
main = do
          print(sum'[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])
```

It is currently very messy and extremely inefficient (not to mention broken). Any help on the functions of haskell which will help me is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if the list contains only one or two items?

Comment: That is a good question and such a list would not work with this program. However, for the task in hand the string 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 is all that is needed

Comment: "split after the nth term, in this case 2" .... `splitAt 1` isn't doing that. also, you have three different definitions for the same name, `sum'`. you can't do that in Haskell, must use different name for each. names should make sense, too. you "define a function to reverse" and then call it ... `sum'`? it could be very difficult to use properly, for some / many, and not make a mistake. good names make it easier for us to write correct code.

Answer (score 1):

Working with the ends of lists is hard.  My suggestion would be to [reverse](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reverse) the list and [take](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:take) 2 elements off the front.

```
let a:b:_ = reverse [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] in a + b
```

By the way what you have here is not a String but a List of Int.  While Strings are always lists in Haskell, not all Lists are Strings

Comment: (strings are lists of `Char`s)

Answer (score 0):

You should recurse until only two elements are left in the list. So you implement two clauses for the normal behavior, and like some extra ones for the "corner cases".

The base case (1) is a list of two elements in which you need to sum up the elements; the recursive case (2) deals with a list with three or more elements, and recurses on the tail of the list:

```
sumlast2 :: Num a => [a] -> a
sumlast2 [x1, x2] = …         -- (1)
sumlast2 (_:xs@(_:_:_)) = …   -- (2)
-- … extra clauses for corner cases …
```

where you still need to fill in the `…` parts. In the second clause (2), `xs` is thus tail of the list: a list with all elements except the first one. You thus will need to define `sumlast2` with three or more elements in terms of `sumlast2`.

Comment: you talk of defining the list. The task requires the list to be declared in the main via the `print(sum'[1,2,3,4,5,6,7])` command. How would I link this declaration with your solution?

Comment: @person2000: no we define the `sumlast2` function, so you use `print(sumlast2 [1 .. 7])`.

Comment: Edit = the sum' function as I've declared is not necessary and can be used without however the result of the program must show in a 'print result of function on this list' command.

Comment: ahh i see. and it looks like you responded before I could amend my question.